# how to call python scripts from php

Tags: php, python, csv, python-2.x

I need to pass a value from PHP to a Python script which then writes the value into a csv file. But, I'm having difficulties, my python when called writes an empty csv file. What could be the problem.

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['data'])){
  $data = $_POST['data'];
  $result = exec("python processData.py .$data");
  echo $result;
  }                
 ?>
```

and processData.py

```
import nltk
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from nltk import stem
import re   
import sys
import csv

mysentence = sys.argv[1]
f = open("output.csv", "wb")
tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(mysentence)
d = [i.lower() for i in tokens if (not tokens in stopwords.words('english'))]    
porter = nltk.PorterStemmer()
for t in tokens:
    result = porter.stem(t)    
    f.write(result+"\n")
    print result
f.close()
```

Comment: You might try opening the file in append "a" mode so that any previous files are not overwritten.

Comment: A few observations not directly related to your question:  You assign to `d` but you do not use the result.  `if (not tokens in stopwords.words('english'))` is not idiomatic Python.  It would be better to write `if tokens not in stopwords.words('english')`.

Comment: even then he is evaluating for each `i in tokens` when it only depends on tokens as a whole ... likely a large slowdown\

Answer (score 1):

```
$result = exec("python processData.py .$data");
```

is likely the problem if you typed : `$data = "hello little world";`
it woudl pass as

```
 $result = exec("python processData.py .hello little world");
```

sys.argv would be

```
  ["processData.py",".hello","little","world"]
```

unfortunately im not sure how nltk would handle that but surely not as you are intending

as an aside

```
d = [i.lower() for i in tokens if (not tokens in stopwords.words('english'))]
```

should be rewriten

```
if  tokens not in stopwords.words('english'):
   d = [i.lower() for i in tokens]
else: #if your actually planning on using d anywhere ... currently your just throwing it out
      # not using d makes all of this just as effective as a pass statement
   d = []
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the **.** before $data, try this:

```
$result = exec("python processData.py {$data}");
```

Regards!

Comment: @grphes, it didnt work. From cmd processData.py "my data" works, but it wouldnt work from php

Answer (score 0):

There is no issue with the `exec()` or anything.  The problem is that the `nltk` module is not able to locate the `nltk_data` directory. For it just locate where the `nltk_data` is present in your system: usually `~/nltk_data`. Now import add that path when you run the function.

```
import nltk;
```

Now, `nltk.data.path` is a list of locations where to search for the modules. You can just do:

```
nltk.data.path.append("your location/directory");
```